# MySQL/MariaDB - query Searching in table via a reference table

Tags: mysql, select, reference, foreign-keys, mariadb

I currently have three tables:

```
    desc products;
+----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(255) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name           | text              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| desc_short     | text              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc tags;
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(255) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tag        | varchar(255)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| iscategory | tinyint(4)        | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc products_tags;
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id | int(255) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| tag_id     | int(255) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

products_tags is actually a reference table that I've created with:

```
CREATE TABLE product_tags (
    product_id INT(255) UNSIGNED, 
    tag_id INT(255) UNSIGNED, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_products_id FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)  REFERENCES tags(id)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_tag_id   FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I'm trying to filter items from the table products by searching for a corresponding tag.
I have already found some [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558282/mysql-select-column-from-another-table-via-a-reference-table) but I couldn't get it to work properly....

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please read documentation on mysql. Foreignkey reference DOESN'T automatically connect related tables.  You must use JOIN to enable the actual relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this join query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.desc_short
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_tag pt
    ON p.id = pt.product_id
INNER JOIN tags t
    ON t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE t.tag = 'some tag'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that indeed works.
Could you please tell me why I have to write p.* where I normally put the table name. (that actually confused me in the first place in other examples).

Comment: @derped :  One must tell mysql EXPLICIT target table name and column name when joins happens. Because table name can be very long, we may replace it with short alias name (i.e. `FROM product p` or more specific   `FROM product "p" `)